# Why is after effects turning my Prores audio into white noise

Tags: audio, after-effects, prores

I have some footage that I converted from red to prores444. I am able to view the converted mov in quicktime and the audio sounds fine. However, I when import it to Efter Effects, the audio previews and exports as white noise, I can see the waveform in the audiotrack, but it won't play. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that AfterEffects is assuming something about the audio format which Quicktime is handling correctly but AE is not.  Check your format settings; you might need to specify a different byte ordering (also called "byte swapping") or tell it to be explicitly 16-bit instead of, say, 24-bit.  In Quicktime you can see what the audio format is via the movie inspector.

Comment: +1 - The alignment is off. Expanding on what fluffy said, depending on the format the audio is in, check to see the format as far as PCM vs other raw formats; their sample size (16bit vs 24/32bit, etc) might be the *same* but the wait the samples are ordered might be off.

Also check interleaving settings.